# Is there a meaning difference between "each" and "every" as NP modifier?

Tags: english, semantics, pragmatics, quantifiers

I have an ineffable feeling that there is a pragmatic difference between "each N" and "every N", which has to do with evaluating the individuals denoted by "each N" one at a time, vs. evaluating them en masse with "every N". This may be an illusion, however. My question is whether there is any clear semantic / pragmatic difference between "each" and "every" as NP modifiers.

There are obscure syntactic differences between "each" and "every" as NP modifiers, such as the fact that you can say "almost every linguist" but not *"almost each linguist", with an adverb preceding the modifier: got that, not considering that context. I'm kicking out plural NPs ("{every / each} 4 days"; "{every / each} 4 books") as outside the realm of investigation. Bare "each" and "every" are clearly different: only looking at these as NP modifiers.

I am trying to develop an operational test to distinguish between two words in another language that are translated (consistently by speakers, who have a reasonable command of British-based English) as "each" vs. "every".

Comment: Here is McCawley's discussion of the difference; https://books.google.com/books?id=HqA4vIhRZIIC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=each+every+logic&source=bl&ots=o1fXxHqnmj&sig=zvjxn_9pPCU4RwkGEqMIdDTySLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq-KuexszOAhWGOyYKHR-YAO0Q6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=each%20every%20logic&f=false

Comment: Yup. That nails it, all right. The paper by Vendler that McCawley refers to is ["Each and Every, Any and All"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2252113)

Comment: could you please add sentences wherein you'd like the use differentiated? I'll give it a go then :)

Comment: Well, I want to know if *vʊrí ʊmwáana* means the same thing as *kɪra ʊmwáana*. In other words, I'm trying to find sentence pairs that could tease of the difference, if there is one, in Logoori.